# Is it necessary to use GROUP BY in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Is it necessary to use `GROUP BY` while you use an aggregate function with column in Oracle?

In MySQL, if I don't use it's working fine, but in Oracle, it gives me an error.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you're concerned about. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always use `GROUP BY` when using aggregate functions. Not using `GROUP BY` is a non-standard SQL extension allowed by MySQL.

**RANT**

IMHO, this extension is brain-dead, outright dangerous and should never be used at all because MySQL returns values for a *random* row for the non-aggregated columns.

**END_OF_RANT**

Comment: I am asking about oracle...I know its ill logical.I haven't idea about oracle.Will it  give error in oracle?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary - not only in Oracle, but in every other RDBMS, as well (apart from MySQL).

Comment: In addition to what Frank has said, the only time you don't need a group by clause in Oracle is if you're aggregating across the entire result set - eg. `select max(col1) from some_table`.

Comment: Thanks Frank and Boneist

Answer (score 8):

It's necessary *if* you select at least one column without an aggregate function.

So, this will work:

```
select sum(col_1), avg(col_2) from table_1;
```

while this wont:

```
select sum(col_1), avg(col_2), col_3 from table_1;
```